# Conformal map between simple and doubly connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

I know that, according to the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem), for any non-empty simply connected open subset $U$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ which is not all of $\mathbb{C}$, then there exists a conformal map from $U$ onto the open unit disk.

I am wondering if it possible to find conformal (or quasi-conformal) maps between regions having different numbers of holes. For example: between an annulus (which is doubly connected) and a square (which is simply connected).

Comment: This should answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030368/42969

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, in the post you mentioned, the focus is on * biholomorphic* maps. Is "conformal" equivalent to "biholomorphic"?

Comment: Yes. And as stated in the answer, you only need a homeomorphisms, i.e. a continuous and bijective function.

Comment: Ok, so it is *not* possible to establish a *conformal* mapping between -say- an annulus and -say- a square. Does it exist some sort of mappings between such figures which is not strictly conformal (i.e. featuring weaker properties)? I heard about quasi-conformal mappings, for example. I apologize for being somehow vague but the question originates from a Physics problem.

Comment: As stated in the other answer, there is no continuous and bijective mapping between single- and multiply-connected domains. That excludes also quasi-conformal mappings.

Comment: If by conformal you mean a mapping that preserves sizes and directions of angles, then yes, the Ahlfors map - which is holomorphic, and thus conformal, provides a mapping from a doubly (n-connected) domain to the unit disc - and by composition to any conformally equivalent domain. This map is 2 to 1 in (n to 1) the case of a doubly connected (n-connected) domain.